# Odoo - Confirm Sales Order

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

Hi I am using Odoo10 and trying to create a sales order in POS, below code creates the Sales orders quotation. I want to Confirm the Sale and create Sales order not quotation.

```
@api.model
    def create_sales_order(self, orderline, customer_id, sign):
        sale_pool = self.env['sale.order']
        prod_pool = self.env['product.product']
        sale_line_pool = self.env['sale.order.line']
        sale_no = ''
        sale = {}
        if customer_id:
            customer_id = int(customer_id)
            sale = {'partner_id': customer_id, 
                    'partner_invoice_id': customer_id,
                    'partner_shipping_id': customer_id, 
                    'signature': sign}
            sale_id = sale_pool.create(sale)
            if sale_id:
                sale_brw = sale_id
                sale_brw.onchange_partner_id()
                #create sale order line
                for line in orderline:
                    sale_line = {}
                    if line.get('product_id'):
                        prod_rec = prod_pool.browse(line['product_id'])
                        sale_line.update({'name': prod_rec.name or False,
                                          'product_id': prod_rec.id,
                                          'product_uom_qty': line['qty'],
                                          'discount': line.get('discount'),
                                          'order_id': sale_id.id})
                        sale_line_id = sale_line_pool.create(sale_line)
                        for line in sale_line_id:
                            line.product_id_change()
        return {"name": sale_brw.name, "id": sale_brw.id }
```

How do I create sales order not quotation?

Comment: You haven't asked anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: Set `state` to `"sale"`:

```
    sale = {'partner_id': customer_id, 
            'partner_invoice_id': customer_id,
            'partner_shipping_id': customer_id, 
            'signature': sign,
            'state': 'sale'}
```

Sale orders and Quotations are saved on the same model (namely, `sale.order`) you can tell whether it is a SO or a Quote by looking at its `state`:

```
state  | Meaning
-------|--------
draft  | Quotation
sent   | Quotation Sent
sale   | Sales Order
done   | Locked
cancel | Cancelled
```

Also, you can look at the function `action_confirm` which is triggered by clicking on the *Confirm Sale* button on `addons/sale/models/sale.py` file:

```
    445     def action_done(self):
    446         return self.write({'state': 'done'})
...
    451     @api.multi
    452     def action_confirm(self):
    453         for order in self:
    454             order.state = 'sale'
    455             order.confirmation_date = fields.Datetime.now()
    456             if self.env.context.get('send_email'):
    457                 self.force_quotation_send()
    458             order.order_line._action_procurement_create()
    459         if self.env['ir.values'].get_default('sale.config.settings', 'auto_done_setting'):
    460             self.action_done()
    461         return True
```

Comment: Anytime! Glad to ear it!